# How do I bind to beforeSubmit event on an AJAX-loaded form in Yii?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yii2

I have a form that I load dynamically via AJAX. I try to bind `beforeSubmit` on the form, but it seems to fail as the form is submitting and the browser is loading a new page. When the form was static in the page, the `beforeSubmit` event handler was working and the browser did not change location. I tried to change from `$('#emailForm').on('beforeSubmit', function(event) {` to below but it didn't work. How do I attach `beforeSubmit` on the form?

`view`

```
        <div id="emailBody"><!-- Placeholder for email form w/CAPTCHA --></div>
        <?#= $this->render('_email_form.php', ['emailModel' => new EmailModel()]) ?>
```

`partial`

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'emailForm', 'action' => 'send-email', 'method' => 'post', 'enableAjaxValidation' => false, 'options' => ['class' => '']]) ?> 
  <?= $form->field($emailModel, 'fromName') ?>
```

`JavaScript`

```
jQuery(function() {
    $('#emailModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) { // load email form w/CAPTCHA
        $('#emailBody').load('email-form');
    });
    $('#emailBody').on('beforeSubmit', '#emailForm', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
```

`rendered HTML`

```
<div id="emailBody"><form id="emailForm" class="" action="send-email" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="aS1LcTJfeU4tXHkuQG4yCjYbDCMfLTEMLEB4EwY4TygGaAAJdBNMPw==">
```

Not that it's relevant, I'm using PHP, Bootstrap, and Yii framework.

Comment: I did some deep searching, and I'm doing almost exactly like this: http://mushtaqtahir.com/blog/3/yii2-ajax-form-submission

Comment: I have a strong feeling the `beforeSubmit` event is bound by Yii, and Yii is not firing the event. I changed `beforeSubmit` to just `submit` and that does call the function, but now Yii validations are not working and my method doesn't know how to handle the validation errors returned.

Comment: Can you show us a jsFiddle of what you're attempting to do?

Comment: @GregBorbonus Sorry that wouldn't be possible because it depends on [Yii Framework](http://www.yiiframework.com/) which isn't a Javascript file like JQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ActiveForm generates the javascript needed to initialize it here: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/49aec24ae1f01d51b4f3cec8e44d44387022d06b/framework/widgets/ActiveForm.php#L201-L206

For this Javascript code to be executed on the client side, you have to ensure the following:

1. make sure the registered JS is part of the response, which should be the case if you render the view with [renderAjax()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-controller.html#renderAjax%28%29-detail) in the controller.
2. Javascript contained in the response is executed. According to the [JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) this is the case for an ajax request, if `dataType` setting is set to `html`:

   > `"html"`: Returns HTML as plain text; included script tags are evaluated when inserted in the DOM.

Comment: Wow, `renderAjax()` is what I needed! Wasn't aware of that. This was my controller action which rendered the partial: `public function actionEmailForm() {
    $this->layout = false;
    return $this->render('_email_form', ['emailModel' => new EmailModel()]);    
  }` As you can see, it didn't include `yii.validation.js` nor any of the other scripts.

Comment: btw: using `renderAjax()` or `renderPartial()` you would not need to set `$this->layout = false;`.

Answer (score 1):

You're executing your beforeSubmit, while the form is not yet present on the dom.

Try this:

```
jQuery(function() {
    $('#emailModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) { // load email form w/CAPTCHA
        $('#emailBody').load('email-form',function(){
            $(this).on('beforeSubmit', function(event) {
             event.preventDefault();
             //The rest of your form code.
            });
         });

    });
});
```

Comment: I thought that was what *Direct and Delegated Events* version of [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) was for? Nevertheless, I tried it, but alas, it didn't work. `Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json: "http://localhost:81/project/web/shopping/send-email".
Navigated to http://localhost:81/project/web/shopping/send-email`

Comment: That is showing an issue with your ajax call. The load is an ajax event. so something is not right in your core functionality. The .on applies ONLY AFTER jquery is able to get the element, which if it doesn't exist, it can't get

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$(document).on('beforeSubmit', 'form', function(e) {
   // code here
 }
```

instead of:

```
 $('form').on('beforeSubmit', function(e) {
   // code here
 }
```

Comment: *$(document).on* need to be used  because #<Form> is dynamic html